I can not install docker desktop to my computer
I Tried install docker to my computer but i have an error.i changed my ssd a few days ago.and before i had docker desktop installed but now i have to install it on new ssd but i had an error.i tried lots of things to solve the problem.but i couldn't.please help me.i have this error bottom
Component Docker.Installer.EnableFeaturesAction failed:
konum: Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
--- Özel durumun oluşturulduğu önceki konumdan başlayan yığın izlemesinin sonu ---
konum: System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
konum: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
konum: Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()
I went to official website of docker and tried to download latest version of docker.successfully i installed docker.installer.exe file but when i run it,after some unpacking file logs i have this error
Component Docker.Installer.EnableFeaturesAction failed:
konum: Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
--- Özel durumun oluşturulduğu önceki konumdan başlayan yığın izlemesinin sonu ---
konum: System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
konum: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
konum: Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()
I use windows 11 pro,have 16 gb RAM and  there is no problem with system requirements.

Try a clean installation from scratch. Run the .exe as administrator. Make sure your windows 11 is up to date, sometimes, compatibility issues are resolved with system updates. Check the event viewer for any error messages after attempting installation. Run the .exe with another compatibility mode. You can also try to disable antivirus/firewall as it can interfere with the installation. Also check ssd health with tools as it is new and could be faulty. If nothing is working try contacting the Docker Support.
